# Reading from CSV file in R and formatting dates and times with strptime()

Tags: r

I want to format my timestamp data with `strptime()`

Reading from a txt file as a CSV (`read.csv(time.txt)`). My time.txt only contains one column with dates, time. For example,

```
29/1/12 19:48
30/12/13 21:48 
31/4/13 2:49
```

FYI, been instructed use only `strptime()` function. 
I am getting the result something like this:

```
V1
NA

mydata <- read.csv("time.txt", header = FALSE)
x <- mydata
strptime(x,format = "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
```

Comment: Maybe you are missing the column name ? `strptime(x$V1,format = "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")`

Comment: @RonakShah Yup, that was the problem. Now it works, Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments:

```
strptime(x$V1,format = "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
```